# SSRS Parent Row Group not on first column?

Tags: reporting-services

is there a way to re-order parent row group in SSRS? I need the group to show on the 3rd column instead of first.

```
  Col1 | Col2 | Group1 | Col3| Col4|
  A    | AX   | GroupA | 12  |13   |
  B    | BX   |        | 14  |3    |
  C    | CX   |        | 32  |65   |
  D    | DX   | GroupB | 54  |62   |
  E    | EX   |        | 56  |63   |
  F    | FX   |        | 576 |64   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a group column in the middle of none grouped columns normally but you can get close.

First create your table as normal with `Col1`-`Col4`, then add the parent group using `Group1`.

The table will look like this...

[image]

Next, insert a new column after `Col2` and select `Group1` from the drop down.

The design will look like this...

[image]

Select the new textbox that contains `Group1` and then in the properties panel, set the `HideDuplicates` property to be the name of the row group (as displayed in the row group panel under the main designer). In the case the row group is also called `Group1`

[image]

Finally, delete the original group column (the left column) and choose "Delete columns only" if prompted.

[image]

The final output will look like this...

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to merge the duplicates from Group1 Columns instead of hiding duplicate values? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could set the border style to be expressions to make it look more like they are merged but they won't actually be merged. Something like `=IIF(RowNumber("Group1") = 1 "Solid, Nothing")` where `"Group1"` is the name of your rowgroup.